# Voip Push notification is not working in ios 14 using php

Tags: php, ios

Anyone know what changes required to sent VoIP notification to the ios 14 into php ?

I have confirmed with ios developer and VoIP notification seems working with ios 13 but not with ios 14.

So anyone please suggest some information for the same ?

Furthermore, APNs notifications are also working fine with ios 14 but only issue is coming with VoIP Notification.

So i would like to understand first below thing

1. Is that anything required to change into PHP side or into ios side ?
2. If ios side, Then what changes should be required.
3. If php side, Then what changes should be required.

Appreciate for the help in advance.

Comment: Any Solution? I am facing same issue. I recently created new certs and it has stopped working

Answer (score 2):

Below is the solution which is working fine for me.

1. I have created one file `test.php` and `echo phpinfo();` into it.
2. Then check it's curl version. if you are getting

   curl version >= '7.58.0'

As well as found `HTTP2 => Yes` then server is supported else not.
if not,Then either needs to upgrade your curl version or upgrade php version to confirm that http/2 protocol supportable or not.

3. Once above http/2 support is enabled then you can use below code to sent notification to ios14 device.

CODE :

```
if ( defined("CURL_VERSION_HTTP2") && (curl_version()["features"] & CURL_VERSION_HTTP2) !== 0) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $body ['aps'] = array (
        "alert" => array (
            "status" => 1,
            "title"  => "source:123,destination:456",
            "body"   => "source:123,destination:456",
        ),
        "badge" => 1 ,
        "sound"  => "default"
    );
    $curlconfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/7B0DA62C06F3A4BA41470BE30D6D52BFD92E666BADAFCC943D265C43CB36897E",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body),
        CURLOPT_SSLCERT =>"testing.pem",
        CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => "test123",
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlconfig);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($res === FALSE) {
            echo('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}else{
    echo "No HTTP/2 support on client.";
}
```

Please note, Right now i didn't tested that http/2 is supported to ios13 or not.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I am testing this on iOS 15 and it worked!